# Google Sheets: sumif if item#1 == cheese in column A and item#2 == swiss in column B

Tags: google-sheets, formula

In following sample, I have the value of an item and it is categorized by a main and secondary category. I want my report to generate a (total) by finding all entries in the category column and filter by the sub-category column. For example, this formula should return a single cell that totals all sub-categories for cheddar (15), another cell for swiss (another formula but based off the first) totaling (30), and a third cell for aged (total of 10).
[image: sample data]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for a pivot table:

[image: SO47798764 example]